# How to change line height in div content editable using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Actually I am using the following code:

```js
$('.editable').each(function() {
  this.contentEditable = true;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="editable"></div>
```

Actually `Ctrl+I , Ctrl+B, Ctrl+U`  is working fine to format my content. Is there any way to change selected text line height using jquery. please help to solve my problem

Answer (score 1):

You have an `id="editable"` and try to select it by `class`: `$('.editable')`, this will not work. Change it to this:

HTML

```
<div class="editable"></div>
```

JavaScript

```
$(".editable").attr("contenteditable", "true");
```

CSS

```
.editable:focus{
    line-height: 50px;
}
```

Look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Arg0n/x73kx1ab/1/) JSFiddle.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood, you want to change the line-height CSS property of a text.
For that, you can simply use:

```
$('.editable').css('line-height', '14px');
```

If you want to handle selected text, use:

```
window.getSelection()
```